# Apply Dijkstra in a real sparse matrix in C#

Tags: c#, performance, graph, sparse-matrix, dijkstra

I Have this code to get "`shortest path`" using Dijkstra 
but I know a real problem involves sparse matrices (matrix populated primarily with zeros).

Is there a way to improve efficiency in this code?

If so what improvements?¡

The graph is:

[image]

```
using System;
namespace DijkstraAlgorithm
{


    /*
     * Dijkstra's algorithm, named after its discoverer, Dutch computer scientist Edsger Dijkstra,
     * is a greedy algorithm that solves the single-source shortest path problem for a directed graph
     * with non negative edge weights. For example, if the vertices (nodes) of the graph represent cities
     * and edge weights represent driving distances between pairs of cities connected by a direct road,
     * Dijkstra's algorithm can be used to find the shortest route between two cities. Also, this algorithm 
     * can be used for shortest path to destination in traffic network.
     * Pseudocode
    function Dijkstra(L[1..n, 1..n]) : array [2..n]
    array D[2..n]
    set C 
    C <- {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, …, n}
    for i <- 2 to n
        D[i] <- L[1,i]
    repeat n - 2 times
        v <- C  // minimum D[v] extract to C
        v <- C - {v} 
        for each w in C do
            D[w] <- min(D[w], D[v] + L[v,w])
    return D
     */
    class Dijkstra
    {        
        private int rank = 0;
        private int[,] L;
        private int[] C; 
        public int[] D;
        private int trank = 0;
        public Dijkstra(int paramRank,int [,]paramArray)
        {
            L = new int[paramRank, paramRank];
            C = new int[paramRank];
            D = new int[paramRank];
            rank = paramRank;
            for (int i = 0; i < rank; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < rank; j++) {
                    L[i, j] = paramArray[i, j];
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < rank; i++)
            {
                C[i] = i;
            }
            C[0] = -1;          
            for (int i = 1; i < rank; i++)
                D[i] = L[0, i];
        }
        public void DijkstraSolving()
        {            
            int minValue = Int32.MaxValue;
            int minNode = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < rank; i++)
            {
                if (C[i] == -1)
                    continue;
                if (D[i] > 0 && D[i] < minValue)
                {
                    minValue = D[i];
                    minNode = i;
                }
            }
            C[minNode] = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < rank; i++)
            { 
                if (L[minNode, i] < 0)
                    continue;
                if (D[i] < 0) {
                    D[i] = minValue + L[minNode, i];
                    continue;
                }
                if ((D[minNode] + L[minNode, i]) < D[i])
                    D[i] = minValue+ L[minNode, i];
            }
        }
        public void Run()
        {
            for (trank = 1; trank <rank; trank++)
            {
                DijkstraSolving();
                Console.WriteLine("iteration" + trank);
                for (int i = 0; i < rank; i++)
                    Console.Write(D[i] + " ");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                for (int i = 0; i < rank; i++)
                    Console.Write(C[i] + " ");
                Console.WriteLine("");                
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] L ={
                {-1,  5, -1, -1, -1,  3, -1, -1}, 
                { 5, -1,  2, -1, -1, -1,  3, -1}, 
                {-1,  2, -1,  6, -1, -1, -1, 10}, 
                {-1, -1,  6, -1,  3, -1, -1, -1},
                {-1, -1, -1,  3, -1,  8, -1,  5}, 
                { 3, -1, -1, -1,  8, -1,  7, -1}, 
                {-1,  3, -1, -1, -1,  7, -1,  2}, 
                {-1, -1, 10, -1,  5, -1,  2, -1} 
            };
            Dijkstra clss = new Dijkstra((int)Math.Sqrt(L.Length),L);
            clss.Run();
            Console.WriteLine("Solution is");
            foreach (int i in clss.D)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter for exit.");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

In the code the matrix is an easy one, but if I have an sparse one...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible improvement would be to stop using an array for the graph, and instead use a SparseMatrix class, which will result in better iteration over the matrix's entries.

You can probably find several libraries that provide SparseMatrix implementations:

1. http://www.extremeoptimization.com/QuickStart/SparseMatricesCS.aspx
2. http://sparsematrix.codeplex.com/
3. http://metanumerics.codeplex.com/

Another improvement might be to use multi-threads, but since each iteration of the Dijkstra algorithm is based on the previous iteration, that would have to be done extremely carefully.